# How to debug django (logic) code using django shell in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, django, debugging

I'm developing a django app including custom logic code using Visual Studio Code and I would like to debug my code while interactie via the django shell. Is this possible and if so, what debugging settings are required?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shell is shell and VSCode is VSCode. You cannot debug your code from the shell.

When I need to debug my custom Django code I put `debug.py` file in my project root (where `manage.py` is) and load my Django project manually  i.e. I imitate the Django shell.

```
# Here you should use all the logic that you have 
# in manage.py before execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
# Generally there is only settings module set up:
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

# Initialize django application
import django
django.setup()

# Do what you want to debug and set breakpoints
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.exists()
```

Then just run this file using regular `Python: Current file` debug option

**UPD:**
Now this use-case of Django is docummented:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage

Answer (score 10):

You can definitely debug in Django Shell. A typical `launch.json` configuration for Django Debugging in VSCode already uses `manage.py runserver --noreload` to launch the dev server, so all you have to do is add an additional debugging config that uses `manage.py shell` instead, something like this (may require tweaking depending on your project structure):

```
{
    "name": "Django Shell",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
    "args": [
        "shell"
    ]
}
```

VSCode will launch the Django shell in its build-in terminal.

(Hat-tip to [this related discussion about debugging management commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008730/how-to-debug-django-custom-management-command-using-vs-code) for pointing me in the right direction when I was looking for an answer to this question.)